# Read File line by line in reverse order from specific line number using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below lines in data.txt file

```
Hi
How
Are
You
I am fine
How
about
you?
```

In above file I want to read line in reverse order from line 5 so the output will be

```
I am fine
You
Are
How
Hi
```

I have tried

```
fs = open("filename.txt","r") 
for rec in reversed(fs).readlines():
    print(rec)
```

but here getting all lines from the file. I want to read from specific line number to top.

Comment: Show us what have your tried please.

Comment: I have tried fs = open("filename.txt","r") for rec in reversed(fs).readlines():print(rec)        but here getting all lines from the file I want to read from specific line number to top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    print(f.readlines()[:5][::-1])

# ['I am fine\n', 'You\n', 'Are\n', 'How\n', 'Hi\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to keep a running reversed 5 line buffer:

```
from collections import deque

with open(fn) as f:
    d=deque(maxlen=5)  # change this 5 for the lines in the buffer
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i==5:       # change this 5 for the line of the file  
            print(''.join(d))   
            break
        else:
            d.appendleft(line)
```

Prints:

```
I am fine
You
Are
How
Hi
```

You can also use [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from itertools:

```
from itertools import islice 

with open(fn) as f:
    print(''.join(list(islice(f,0,5))[::-1]))

# same output
```

Explanation:

```
''.join(list(islice(f,0,5))[::-1])
                    ^                iterate over a file line by line
                      ^              starting line
                        ^            ending line
          ^                          turn that into a list
                              ^      reverse the list
   ^                                 file already has \n so just join
```

Comment: I always don't want to read the file till first line in reverse order. I want to read the file say from line number 150 to 100 in reverse order.